# How do I unset k8s context from Jenkins?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, continuous-integration

For testing, I want to unset all k8s informations (cluster, user, context) from Jenkins and test as if it's the first time using the cluster.

Locally, I used

```
kubectl unset contexts
```

but I wonder how I do it for Jenkins.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would ask why you think you need to do this?

The file "~/.kube/config" has all of your context information, including the "current-context".

I suppose if you were to do something like:

```
grep -v "^current-context:" ~/.kube/config > /tmp/kc.$$;cp /tmp/kc.$$ ~/.kube/config
```

This needs more refinement, as this would litter /tmp with temp files if you do this a lot. Best to save that into a variable and have an exit trap to delete it.

However, that is just unsetting the current context.  I don't know what you mean by "cluster" in the things you want to unset.